# Mysql calculation with multiple summands not working

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a query on two columns from two different tables (connected by a left join in my query) and I want to order the search results by the occurence of the term I am looking for. I came up with this as my sorting variable in the statement, which might not be elegant, but works fine:

`((LENGTH(table1.column)-LENGTH(REPLACE(lower(table1.column),lower('$term'),'')))/LENGTH('$term') AS sort_frequency`

$term is my search term and at the end of the query I do this: `ORDER BY sort_frequency DESC`.

Now comes the difficulty: the calculation works fine for both tables separately, but when I want to connect the two by addition, the results of table2 always come in front of the results of table1 and nothing is ordered by occurence. My statement looks like this:

`(((LENGTH(table1.column)-LENGTH(REPLACE(lower(table1.column),lower('$term'),'')))/LENGTH('$term')) + ((LENGTH(table2.column)-LENGTH(REPLACE(lower(table2.column),lower('$term'),'')))/LENGTH('$term'))) AS sort_frequency`

I need this calculation, because the search results come from two different tables, but shall be ordered together on one page (let's say: one table is about images with certain keywords and the second table is about videos with certain keywords, once I searched for a specific keyword I don't care whether it is an image or video, I want the one that fits my keyword query most).

Do you have any idea why the calculation does not work? What is my mistake? I have tried adding/removing brackets, but that does not help.

Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a UNION to combine the two table before searching for occurrences? My Suggestion is to use something along the lines of:

```
SELECT((LENGTH(newcolumn)-LENGTH(REPLACE(lower(newcolumn),lower('$term'),'')))/LENGTH('$term') AS sort_frequency FROM table1.column UNION table2.column AS newcolumn
```

Comment: Aren't the tables already combined by the left join? This is the statement: `SELECT table1.column, table1.joining_column, table2.column, table2.joining_column, (((LENGTH(table1.column)-LENGTH(REPLACE(lower(table1.column),lower('$term'),'')))/LENGTH('$term'))+((LENGTH(table2.column)-LENGTH(REPLACE(lower(table2.column),lower('$term'),'')))/LENGTH('$term'))) AS sort_frequency FROM table1 AS table1 LEFT JOIN table2 AS table2 ON table1.joining_column = table2.joining_column WHERE upper(table1.column) LIKE upper('%$term%') OR upper(table2.column) LIKE upper('%$term%') ORDER BY sort_frequency DESC`

Comment: A left join combines the column values from different tables into the same record. The UNION clause combines the result set from one query with the result set of another query into one result set. Thus it can be used to combine all the records from different tables into one new "virtual" table

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I do not know how to combine my mysql query with the proposed UNION statement. Where do I have to add/include it?

Comment: SELECT t1.column,((LENGTH(t1.column)-LENGTH(REPLACE(lower(t1.column),lower('$term'),'')))/LENGTH('$term') AS sort_frequency FROM (SELECT table1.column FROM table1 UNION SELECT table2.column FROM table2) AS t1 WHERE upper(t1.column) LIKE upper('%$term%') ORDER BY sort_frequency DESC

Comment: Thanks for the complete statement, but that does not work for me. Once I attempt to combine it with my left join, it does not work either. It seems I have to find another solution.

Comment: You shouldn't combine it with your left join. Use it instead of your left join

Comment: I tried to use the `UNION` solution instead of a `LEFT JOIN`, but it does not work. Could it be a problem that I access data from more than a single column of the two tables? The sorting variable "sort_frequency" is generated from only one column of each table, but I still need the data from other columns as well.

Comment: `SELECT t1.column,((LENGTH(t1.column)-LENGTH(REPLACE(lower(t1.column),lower('$term'),'')‌​))/LENGTH('$term') AS sort_frequency FROM (SELECT table1.* FROM table1 UNION SELECT table2.* FROM table2) AS t1 WHERE upper(t1.column) LIKE upper('%$term%') ORDER BY sort_frequency DESC` or something like that